# Export Kotlin code to jar is recognized as Java code on the consumer project

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm working on a multi-module repository. One module exports Kotlin library, and the other one consumes the artifact and uses it.

I've noticed that once I'm trying to use named parameters inside the consumer it tells me that I cannot do this in a non-kotlin code (e.g. from Java). When I've tried to decompile the code of the library I've seen that the code I see there is indeed Java code (however this might be related to the fact that IntelliJ decompile everything into Java?)

The entire code can be found in this following [link](https://github.com/yonatankarp/rabbit-hole) where `demo-app` is the consumer and `rabbit-hole` is the producer

Just for complicity,  I'll put the build gradle file of both here as well:

Library:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen"
    id "jacoco"
    id "maven-publish"
    id "org.springframework.boot"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management"
    id "com.diffplug.spotless"
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name: "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-amqp'

    // Tests
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation group: 'io.mockk', name: 'mockk', version: '1.12.1'

}

build {
    finalizedBy spotlessApply
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy spotlessApply
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.yonatankarp'
            artifactId = project.name
            version = project.version

            from components.java
            versionMapping {
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/yonatankarp/rabbit-hole")
            credentials {
                username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")
                password = project.findProperty("gpr.key") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")
            }
        }
    }
}

allOpen {
    annotation("org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration")
}
```

Consumer:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen"
    id "jacoco"
    id "org.springframework.boot"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management"
    id "com.diffplug.spotless"
}

group = 'com.yonatankarp'
version "${version}"
sourceCompatibility = '11'

jar {
    enabled = false
}

bootJar {
    enabled = true
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "Rabbit Hole"
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/yonatankarp/rabbit-hole")
        credentials {
            username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")
            password = project.findProperty("gpr.key") ?: System.getenv('GITHUB_TOKEN')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name: "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'

    implementation "com.yonatankarp:rabbit-hole:+"

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

build {
    finalizedBy spotlessApply
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy spotlessApply
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

allOpen {
    annotation("org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration")
}
```

**EDIT**

For clarity: Both the library and the consumer of it are written in Kotlin

Comment: Your GitHub link is dead.

Comment: @Tenfour04 sorry, fixed.

Comment: Okay, I didn’t realize your consumer code was in Kotlin before seeing the code in the link. Might be worth mentioning that in your question. I don’t know what would cause this. IntelliJ only decompiles bytecode to Java. There should be metadata in the bytecode identifying Kotlin features for other Kotlin code to be able to use it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, added it for the question. My assumption was as well that some metadata is missing, however I don't know which and how to add it